# DAX statement - "to RETURN, or not to RETURN"

Tags: dax, daxstudio

"Have(ing) fun with DAX"  and wondering why the RETURN statement is not suitable for my examples in the 'NOT works' section.  Thank you in advance.

-- DEFINE can only be used once ie globals
-- EVALUATE VAR RETURN can be used multiple and nested

-- Working

```
EVALUATE
    VAR _return = "test" -- create local variable
RETURN
    { _return }

DEFINE
    VAR _return = "test" -- create global variable
EVALUATE
    { _return }
```

-- Not working

```
DEFINE
    VAR _return = "test"
EVALUATE
RETURN
    { _return }

DEFINE
    VAR _return = "test"
--EVALUATE
RETURN
    { _return }
```

Power BI Community forum post link of same question :

[to RETURN, or not to RETURN](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/DAX-Commands-and-Tips/to-RETURN-or-not-to-RETURN/m-p/3750670)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like it was mentioned in the Fabric Community link, this is a rule sytax.

**1st case :** if you want to use the local Variable Inside EVALUATE:

```
EVALUATE
    VAR _return = "test"
RETURN
    { _return }
```

This works because you are defining a local variable `_return` inside an `EVALUATE` statement and immediately returning it.

In other words, the scope of `_return` is within the `EVALUATE` block, so it isaccessible to the `RETURN` statement.

**2nd case :** Using global Variable with EVALUATE:

```
DEFINE
    VAR _return = "test"
EVALUATE
    { _return }
```

Here, `_return` is defined globally using `DEFINE` outside of any `EVALUATE` context, making it accessible to any `EVALUATE` statement that follows. You are then using this variable directly inside an `EVALUATE` block, so it works.

Coming to the cases where it is failing :

**3rd case :** DEFINE with EVALUATE and RETURN:

```
DEFINE
    VAR _return = "test"
EVALUATE
RETURN
    { _return }
```

The problem here is that `EVALUATE` expects a table expression to follow it directly. So, when you insert `RETURN` immediately after it without any table expression, it will fail. Keep in mind that`RETURN` is not a standalone statement in the context of DAX queries but is used within `VAR` to return a value.

**4th case :** DEFINE and RETURN without EVALUATE:

```
 DEFINE
        VAR _return = "test"
    --EVALUATE
    RETURN
        { _return }
```

Here you are trying to use `RETURN` without an enclosing `EVALUATE` statement, which is not how `RETURN` is designed to be used in the context of DAX queries. `RETURN` is used to return the result of a `VAR` within an `EVALUATE` statement or similar contexts, not as a standalone statement.

Comment: Thanks Amira for your detailed response :}

Comment: @GaryThomann welcome don't forget to accept the answer to help it reach other people :)